# SSL Certificate in IIS

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649647.aspx#Step13 to add Username Authentication in WCF. At the step that I have to create a temporary certificate for SSL, I have the following questions:

1. The server that the WCF will be deployed on its IIS does not have Visual Studio, therefore I am not sure what I'm supposed to do for the part in link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx that Step 3: Create and Install Your Temporary Service Certificate by using Visual Studio command prompt.
2. Also I am using IIS 8, and the steps in Step 13: Configure Security Settings in IIS does not follow smoothly as described in the step by step. If anybody has some experience to configure the Web site in IIS to use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption and anonymous security, I'd appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Ad1)
You can download makecert and put it on the target machine (its just a simple tool no need for full VS) or you can run the command on the different machine it will create and install certificates in the LocalMachine/My store. Then you can export this certificate using mmc tool with certifacate addin and install it on the target machine in the same place (again using mmc). When you are exporting it make sure you have the "include private key" checkbox checked.

Ad2) I dont have access to IIS8 atm but the description on the msdn sounds OK. The only tip i can think of is to make sure you have a port open for HTTPS communication. Its done using httpcfg tool
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx